# Three kinds of spectra

Tags: algebraic-geometry, commutative-algebra

In commutative algebra while proving the Nullstellensatz one introduces for a while the Rabinowitsch sprectrum as:

$$\operatorname{Spec}_{\rm Rab}(R)=\{R\cap \mathfrak m: \mathfrak m \text{ is a maximal ideal of } R[X]\}.$$

There is a quite easy to see the inclusion list: $\operatorname{Spec Max}\subseteq\operatorname{Spec}_{\rm Rab}\subseteq \operatorname{Spec}$. I'm asked to prove that the inclusions are strict, by considering $R=K[[Y]]$, $K$ a field, and $S=R[Z]$ by using the ideals $(Y)$ and $(Z)$ in $S$.

Im kinda stuck, any kind of help would be helpful, and not very familiar with the ring of formar series. Thank you

This is an exercise in the book *A Course in Commutative Algebra* from George Kemper, page 20 number 1.4.

Comment: Dear user, It would be good to link to the MO question where you first asked this. Also, if you read the comments to that question, you would have learned that the terminology "Rabinowitsch spectrum" is not standard, but rather appears just in the text-book you are studying (where it is acknowledged as being ad hoc).  So it would be good to also include this information in your question.   Finally, this is is just *one* possible proof of the Nullstellensatz, of which there are many (see e.g. various MO questions on this), and so, rather than writing "... while proving the nullstellensatz", ...

Comment: ... it would be good to indicate that this is a particular proof of the Nullstellensatz that you are trying to follow, from a particular book (and, again, include the title/author of the book).  In short, it is good to include all the relevant information about your question in your question, since it makes the job of those who might answer it much easier.  Regards,

Comment: @user56741: Wlecome to MSE! It would also be helpful to format all of your posting using MathJax. Regards

Comment: Btw, the author is called Gregor, not George! It‘s a German name.

Answer (score 2):

It is clear that $(y,z)_S$ is a maximal ideal of $S$. 
Now I claim $(z)_S$ is a not maximal prime ideal in $S$, and belongs to the Rabinowitsch Spectrum. Let $\mathbf{m}$ be the ideal $(1-X*y,z)_{S[X]}$ of $S[X]$. It is maximal since the quotient of $S[X]$ by $\mathbf{m}$ is the field $K( (y) )$ of the Laurent series in $y$, and clearly $\mathbf{m}\cap S=(z)_S$.

Moreover $(y)_s$ is clearly prime but not maximal in $S$ and does not belong to the Rabinowitsch Spectrum, since if $\mathbf{m}$ is a maximal ideal of $S[X]$ such that $\mathbf{m}\cap S=(y)_s$, it should contain $(y)_SS[X]$. Then we get a surjective morphism from $S[X]/(y)_SS[X]=K[X,z]$ to the field $S[X]/\mathbf{m}$. If we suppose $K$ algebraically closed, then we have $S[X]/\mathbf{m}=K$, since the kernel of this morphism is a maximal ideal of the polynomial ring $K[X,z]$. This is a contradiction with the fact that $S/\mathbf{m}\cap S = S/(y)_s = K[z]$ injects in $K=S[X]/\mathbf{m}$.

Comment: Actually, we do not need to suppose $K$ algebraically closed. In the previous proof, we get that $S[X]/\mathbf{m}$ is a field which is also a finitely generated $k$-algebra, so it is an algebraic extension of $k$, a contradiction with the fact that it contains $K[z]$.

Answer (score 0):

For $R=K[[Y]]$, to show that $\text{Spec}_{\text{rab}}(R) \subsetneq \text{Spec}_{\text{max}}(R)$, we consider the ideal $(0)_R$.

It can be shown that $(Y)_R$ is the only maximal ideal of $R$, so $(0)_R$ is not a maximal ideal of $R$.

Now, consider the surjective evaluation homomorphism $\varphi: R[Z]\to R[Y^{-1}], f\mapsto f(Y^{-1})$, where $Z$ is an other intermediate.
It can be shown that $R[Y^{-1}]$ is a field: $R[Y^{-1}]=\text{Quot}(R)=:R((Y))$, the field of formal Laurent series with $Y$ an intermediate.

The kernel $\text{ker}(\varphi)$ of the above homomorphism is a maximal ideal in $R[Z]$, because $R[Y^{-1}]$ is a field (and by using the first isomorphism theorem).
And we have $\text{ker}(\varphi) \cap R = \{0\}$, because for a polynomial $f\in R[Z]$ to satisfy $f(Y^{-1})=0$, its "constant term", which can be seen as an element in $R$, must be zero.

Hence, $(0)_R \in \text{Spec}_{\text{rab}}(R) \setminus \text{Spec}_{\text{max}}(R)$.